# JSONIX: Get restrictions and default value for properties

Tags: javascript, xml, json, jsonix

I am using JSONIX for marshalling and unmarshalling XML files. So far it works pretty well. What I am missing is the possibility to get default values and restrictions like minOccours and maxOccours-Values. Is this somehow possible with JSONIX?

These properties:

```
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="inflowMin" type="framework:flowType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xsd:element name="inflowMax" type="framework:flowType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xsd:element name="unitOfFlowControl" type="framework:flowUnit" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="waterCosts" type="xsd:double" default="0.0"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="controllable" type="xsd:boolean" default="0"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="scalingOfControl" type="xsd:double" default="1.0" />
```

Get:

```
    propertyInfos: [{
        type: 'element',
        name: 'inflowMin',
        elementName: 'inflowMin',
        typeInfo: ...
    }, {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'inflowMax',
        elementName: 'inflowMax',
        typeInfo: ...
    }, {
        type: 'element',
        name: 'unitOfFlowControl',
        elementName: 'unitOfFlowControl',
        typeInfo: 'String'
    }, {
        name: 'waterCosts',
        typeInfo: 'Double',
        attributeName: 'waterCosts',
        type: 'attribute'
    }, {
        name: 'controllable',
        typeInfo: 'Boolean',
        attributeName: 'controllable',
        type: 'attribute'
    }, {
        name: 'scalingOfControl',
        typeInfo: 'Double',
        attributeName: 'scalingOfControl',
        type: 'attribute'
    }]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you requested is now implemented in [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix) [2.3.2](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/releases/tag/2.3.2) and [Jsonix Schema Compiler](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-schema-compiler) [2.3.7](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-schema-compiler/releases/tag/2.3.7).

Jsonix Schema Compiler now produces `required`, `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` in the generated mappings and the JSON schema.

This is how it looks in the mappings:

```
  {
    localName: 'Items',
    propertyInfos: [{
        name: 'item',
        minOccurs: 0,
        maxOccurs: 100,
        collection: true,
        elementName: {
          localPart: 'item'
        },
        typeInfo: '.Items.Item'
      }]
  }
```

And in the JSON Schema:

```
    "Items":{
        "type":"object",
        "title":"Items",
        "properties":{
            "item":{
                "title":"item",
                "allOf":[
                    {
                        "type":"array",
                        "items":{
                            "$ref":"#/definitions/Items.Item"
                        },
                        "maxItems":100,
                        "minItems":0
                    }
                ],
                "propertyType":"element",
                "elementName":{
                    "localPart":"item",
                    "namespaceURI":""
                }
            }
        },
        "typeType":"classInfo",
        "typeName":{
            "localPart":"Items",
            "namespaceURI":""
        },
        "propertiesOrder":[
            "item"
        ]
    }
```

You can access this metadata from the Jsonix context as follows:

```
    var context = new Jsonix.Context([ PO ]);
    var itemsClassInfo = context.getTypeInfoByName("PO.Items");
    var itemPropertyInfo = itemsClassInfo.getPropertyInfoByName("item");
    test.equal(false, itemPropertyInfo.required);
    test.equal(0, itemPropertyInfo.minOccurs);
    test.equal(100, itemPropertyInfo.maxOccurs);
    test.done();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author.

At the moment not, this information is not generated yet. There was [this issue](http://jira.highsource.org/browse/JSNX-26) back then, but it was not implemented.

If you're interested in this functionality, please file two issues [here](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-schema-compiler/issues) (one for the default value and the other one for `minOccurs`/`maxOccurs`).

In principle, this information is available from the XML Schema, but in some cases it is not clearly mappable to the generated model. In a few weird cases like repeatable choice or sequence this won't work, but in most cases it will. So it is implementable, please file the issues.

Do you just need these things in the generated mappings? Or some kind of API to access it?

Comment: Both solutions would work for me. I think it would be more consistent if you could add these information to the generated mappings. Thanks a lot for your support! I will file the issues!

Comment: @mapf Thank you for filing the issues. I'll see what I can do.